# MySQL 5.7 and connection attribute

Tags: python, mysql, connection, mysql-5.7

I have looked everywhere and well researched into different solutions. I have come closer to the solution by reducing the number of errors. Here is my piece of code that's giving me a headache

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'BucketList'

mysql.init_app(app)
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
```

I have been running the app.py file and keep getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'connection'.

I am using MySQL 5.7 and attempting to create my first web app using a tutorial that's dated back in time. The above piece of code is after editing it closer to relevant standards.

Answer (score 0):

The part of your code in which you instantiate the `MySQl()` object is incorrect. Instead of:

```
mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
```

It should be

```
app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL(app)
```